# How to save MySql connection ?

Tags: c#, mysql, connection, ado

I want to save a MySql connection in my app.
This is what I want to do :

1. Running the setConnForm, then insert host, port, username, password, and database name from     textbox, and save it.
2. Then running the loginForm to get in to the main application
3. Finally when the main application form closed and run again, it doesn't need to set the connection from setConnForm again. (Because I have saved the connection before)

How can I do this ?

Thanks Before

Comment: What did you try? What are you having trouble with? Are you asking how to create a form? How to pass data? How to save the connection string to a file?

Comment: i was create another project, so i have 2 projects in one solution, i don't know how to use project number 2 that i want only used to set MySql connection and save it to some variable or app.config

Comment: Please pay more attention to your question formatting and write it more clear.

Comment: thank you Hamed Shams, sorry for my bad english, i just don't know how to write it down

Answer (score 0):

Just save the connectionstring datas, (for example: User Id, Password, Server, etc) into a Text file, or with `WriteLines` any oder format, line by line. And when you need the User ID or the others read it with `Readlines` line by line. I use this solution, of course without PWD saving.

I hope this will help.

Comment: if i close the main form, then i run the LoginForm and try to Log In to the application again, do i need to set the connection again?

Comment: If you not close the whole application, just the Form, you can create a global variable in the Parent From and the Readlines will be here read the values and u can use it in the continues. 
So if your main form is the parent, u need always call the read method if u want use the connectiostring

Comment: how if i close the whole app? and how to save the connection? thanks

Comment: in this case u need always in the Form_load event call the ReadLines method and load the datas into a variable and after this u can use in your ConnString